Python - Removing Lines Before and After a text string
Iv'e written a simple script to remove lines from a text file and write to a new file based on keywords:
def remove_line(line, ICE_words):
    return any([word in line for word in ICE_words])

ICE_words = [
             "_Amb_" , "_fuel_",
            ]

with open('Inputs.txt','r') as infile:
    with open('Outputs.txt','w') as Include_in_A2L:
        for line in infile:
            if not remove_line(line, ICE_words):
                Include_in_A2L.write(line)

But now, I would like to also remove the lines until it reaches the line containing "/end":
Example .txt file:

/begin MEASUREMENT Amb_air_temp "Ambient air temperature"
        data1
        data2
/end MEASUREMENT

/begin MEASUREMENT fuel_value "Fuel injection value per stroke"
        data1
        data2
/end MEASUREMENT


My current script is able to write a new text file excluding the line that the keyword is found in, but I can't figure out the best way to have it continue removing lines until it reaches "/end". I would like the script to perform this for every keyword listed in ICE_words; so i'm guessing some kind of loop.
Thank you,
I tried to use the split function, but am having difficultly as how to integrate it into a loop, and have it stop at "/end"

Your title says "before and after". But you only want to remove lines after the matching string.

Use a flag variable to track whether you're in a block that you're writing or skipping.
with open('Inputs.txt','r') as infile, open('Outputs.txt','w') as Include_in_A2L:
    writing = True
    for line in infile:
        if line.startswith('/begin') and remove_line(line, ICE_words)
            writing = False
        elif writing:
            Include_in_A2L.write(line)
        elif line.startswith('/end'):
            writing = True

